# How do I allow users to change their password (ASP.NET membership)

Tags: asp.net, password, forms-authentication

I've an ASP.Net membership database (extranet) site set up, but users have no way to change their passwords.How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Community Kit for SharePoint has a [Forms Authentication Solution](http://www.codeplex.com/CKS/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=17901) containing a Change Password web part. It also has much more (straight copy/paste):

- Automated Solution Deployment - Zac Smith
- Membership request webpart (including CAPTCHA) - Paul Ballard
- Membership request list - Paul Ballard
- Login web part - Paul Ballard
- Recover Password web part - Edin Kapic
- Change Password web part - Edin Kapic
- ULS Logging - Edin Kapic
- User Management - Zac Smith
- Role Management - Zac Smith
- User Properties - Brendon Schwartz
- Fixes - Anthony Sumner, Mike Sharp

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the ChangePassword ASP.NET control:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/changepassword.aspx